# Search text box for Search API + Database + Search Views + Facets API + Facets Bonus

Tags: 7, views, search

I have check boxes and radio buttons (after a few patches) in my facets, using Search views.  I want to be able to present the user with a text search box so they can search for a title and another text field.  I can't seem to find this, however.

Do I need to create a new facet, or am I just missing this functionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should enable title and other fields for search in your search index.
Select type as "Fulltext". Reindex content. 
After that add new exposed filter in your search view. It's fulltext search filter. In settings of this filter you can select your fields from index.

Comment: I noticed I can't clear this with my Current search filters block.  Is there a way I can clear this search box with the other filters?

Comment: hm, I not understand very well, but maybe hook_form_alter can help you?