# Order of search results for exact match content

Tags: search

I am using Search API module with Search API DB module to use drupal database for search indexing.

Issue is when I do a phrase search as following "test content" I get results having "test"(let's say nid:1) or "content"(nid:2) or "test content"(nid:3) in them but the content having exact match which is "test content" which is node 3 shows down in the search results.

I do not have any fields for sorting in my search view.

My question is why I am not getting search results on phrase match on top of those who have partial matches?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Notice that, technically, you aren't asking any explicit question; you are just stating some facts.

Comment: thanks @kiamlaluno, Yes and I realised it later after getting the answer from cedric_a . I was expecting the search results to consider phrase match, but got to know core search does not support it.

Comment: Please edit the question to ask an explicit question. Comments are second-class citizens, and should not be used to re-open an on hold question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Database search doesn't support phrases searches as stated here by the maintainer of the module (cf. https://www.drupal.org/node/2043339#comment-7654017) :

> Are you using the Database Search backend? In this case it's clear, because that backend currently doesn't support phrase searches due to technical restrictions.
>   However, results should always contain both words, though not necessarily next to each other.

In order to sort your results, see this related question/answer [I have no fields available for sorting with Search API sorts module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/105936/i-have-no-fields-available-for-sorting-with-search-api-sorts-module)